# Clean up Named Range Addresses with Errors (e.g. #REF!)

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I set up a named range, let's call him RngIn.
He has 3 cells, and his address refers to A1:A3

Next, I delete Row 2.

My RngIn now shows #REF! error (correctly) in its RefersTo property:
"=A1,Sheet1!#REF!,A2"

This means I cannot manipulate the rest of that named range using VBA, because of the Method 'Range' of Global Object error.

The range is created during a process, and if a user subsequently needs to delete one row for whatever reason, my future code will fail because it needs to know where the rest of the named range data is...

I have tried many ways to access the remaining address information for this range, in VBA, but failed so far, e.g.

```
Dim RngAddress As String
Dim RngIn As Range

Set RngIn = Range("A1:A3")
RngAddress = RngIn.Address
RngAddress = RngIn.RefersToRange.Address
RngAddress = RngIn.RefersTo
RngAddress = Replace(RngIn.Address, "Sheet1!#REF!", "")
```

What I ideally want to see in a text string as the result for RngIn is: 
"=A1,A2" 
Because A2 is now the location of the data which was originally in A3.

Comment: Do you have more rows of data below A3?  You could just redefine the named range.  I use a worksheet_change event to detect the change, get the new last row and recreate the nam.  Something like thisworkbook.names(“my name”).referstorange = mysheet.cells(1,1).resize(lastrow,1)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, but that won't work. My range is not contiguous (the cells aren't really A1, A2, A3 but more like A70, A104, A106, etc.). I should've made that more clear in the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand this well: your example code does not use Defined Names (aka Named Ranges).
lets suppose you create a Name called RangeIn that refers to A1,A3,A5 and you then delete Row 3.

The RefersTo for RangeIn is now `=Sheet1!$A$1,Sheet1!#REF!,Sheet1!$A$4`

This code removes the Sheet1!#REF!, to leave the Name RangeIn referring to `=Sheet1!$A$1,Sheet1!$A$4`

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Sub ChangeRef()
Dim strAd As String
strAd = ThisWorkbook.Names("RangeIn").RefersTo
strAd = Replace(strAd, "Sheet1!#REF!,", "")
ThisWorkbook.Names("RangeIn").RefersTo = strAd
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, I set the start and end points of my named ranges to be the cell above and the cell below the range where the user can delete, and then use the OFFSET or INDEX function to resize that range to exclude my bookmarks. Or I use Excel Tables, which can handle row deletions without returning #REF errors.